# Type Error in RSpec controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am having troubles with an RSPec test.  The test does a PUT with some objects in the request.  The controller which receives the PUT seems to be not getting the correct values

For example, 'put :update, :id => @channel.id, :channel => @channel, :tags => @tag' Then, in the Controller, when I try to use params[:tags] there is an integer in that location.  A Gist with the Spec and the controller method is at https://gist.github.com/3715021

This started happening when I upgraded from Rails 3.0.13 to 3.1.8

Any idea what might be happening here and how to resolve it?

Comment: There is no `params[:tag]` being passed in, only `params[:tags]`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry.  I typed the question; the Gist has the actual code includes :tags.  I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `@tag` is an object from your Tags model. When you give Rails an object like

```
`get :action, :foo => foo`
```

or in a url helper (e.g., `foo_path(foo)`),

Rails will turn your object into a parameter suitable for use in a url via the `#to_param` method. You're probably getting an integer because `Tag#to_param` returns the id of the tag in your db.

It looks like your update action, by contrast, expects `params[:tags]` to be a hash, presumably generated from a form that includes fields for values like `tags[:name]`.

I can't help much more without knowing more about the relevant code. But I'm guessing what you want to do is change your test to read

```
put :update, :id => @channel.id, :channel => @channel, :tags => { :name => 'tag' }
```

or something like that, mimicking the params you'd get by actually submitting the form that PUTs to your update action.

Comment: That worked.  Though I'm confused why with Rails 3.0.13, I could pass the object and upgrading to 3.1.8 caused me to have to specify a hash.  Thanks for the help @gregates

Comment: Yeah, me too. I use 3.0.11 at work, and I'm pretty sure passing the object wouldn't work in that version. Are you absolutely sure nothing else changed that could explain why you went from green to red on this test?

Comment: Yep.  I was following the Railscast on upgrading Rails.  I ran the autotest, changed the gemfile to use Rails 3.1.8 and started Autotest again.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to help you because we don't know what you're trying to do.  For example, it would be helpful if you showed more of the test (for example, the values you set as your variables) and the specific results of the test.

Anyway, is the @tags variable an arel object?  and if so, are you expecting the ID as the value to be passed?  If not, then you probably want to specify the attribute referenced in @tags.  For example, @tags.name...  Or, does @tags reference a hash, itself?

Comment: tag is an object.  When submitted from a form, it's just the contents submitted via the form helper.  However, in the rspec I wrote, pass the object was sufficient until I upgraded to Rails 3.1